# Cannot apply Await and Async properly in C#5.0

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I have the below program that will move files from one directory to other. In sysnchronous way, it works fine.But I want to do it in the asynchronous way.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says it all: you can't `await` something that is `void`. You can only `await` `Task`s and things that look similar to `Task`s (e.g. [`YieldAwaitable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.yieldawaitable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that's returned by [`Task.Yield()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). But you most certainly can't `await` `void`.

There doesn't seem to be a way to asynchronously move a file in .Net 4.5.

The best you can do is to either use something like `await Task.Run(() => fileinfo.MoveTo(target))`, which will still block a thread, but not the current one (may be useful if you're on the UI thread).

Or, alternatively, you could copy the file yourself using `Stream`s (which can be asynchronous) and then delete the original.

Comment: Hi, your suggestion worked but the control does not comes back and hence MessageBox.Show("Files copied successfully") never gets call..what to do?

Comment: That's hard to tell, have you tried debugging the code to see what's actually going on? And is your application responsive while you're moving the files? If not, it may indicate you have a deadlock somewhere (e.g. you're calling `Wait()` or `Result` before a `Task` is finished).

Answer (score 1):

You can only use await when the method you are calling supports it.

To support `await` the method needs to return a `Task<T>`

In this case the `fileInfo.MoveTo` does not return a `Task`

Comment: You can `await` things that are not `Task`s. See e.g. `Task.Yield()` which doesn't return a `Task`, but still can be `await`ed.