# Cannot await 'void' error in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am stuck in this problem. I am creating a Windows Phone application. Here is the code.

```
private async void btn_signup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    obj = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();

    if (!txt_id.Text.Equals("") && !txt_name.Text.Equals("") && !txt_password.Equals(""))
    {
        user r = new user();
        r.ID = txt_id.Text;
        r.FULLNAME = txt_name.Text;
        r.PASSWORD = txt_password.Text;
        var g = await obj.GetDataAsync(r);
        string message = g;

        if (message.Equals("done"))
        {
            lbl_show.Text = "you have signed up !! Hurrah";
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/mainmenu.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_show.Text = " Please fill all the field.Enter again";
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error "cannot await void". I am using WCF service to access the db.
Please guide me with the appropriate solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot apply Await and Async properly in C#5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167783/cannot-apply-await-and-async-properly-in-c5-0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [all wcf methods return void while calling from windows phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949349/all-wcf-methods-return-void-while-calling-from-windows-phone-8)

Comment: I am a new developer so I wanted an answer which would  be quite specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetDataAsync` is not a [TAP method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx); it is an [EAP method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Try to re-create the WCF proxy and tell it to create TAP asynchronous methods. If Visual Studio doesn't give you that option, then see if the proxy has `Begin*`/`End*` methods that you can [wrap into a TAP method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ApmToTap).

If nothing else, you can [wrap the EAP method/event into a TAP method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#EAP).