# Magento async soap C#: Cannot await 'void'

Tags: c#, magento, asynchronous, soap

From the magento api soap I am trying to load informations about orders(i.e. shipping address) but it takes a while befor the grid is filled with data. So now I am trying to use magento async method but I cannot figure out how to set it up. Could you please point me to any information or review the code and point out the mistakes that I have made? Here is what I've got so far:

```
 public void FillFlexGrird(string warehouse, C1FlexGrid grid)
    {
        try
        {
            salesOrderListEntity[] sole = _mageService.salesOrderList(_sessionKey, magentoFilter("status", "eq", "processing", warehouse));
            salesOrderEntity info;
            foreach (salesOrderListEntity msole in sole)
            {
                GetOrderInfo(msole.increment_id);
                //Application.DoEvents();
                int count = grid.Rows.Count;
                grid.Rows.Count++;




                //info = _mageService.salesOrderInfo(_sessionKey, msole.increment_id);
                salesOrderAddressEntity shipTo = info.shipping_address;
                grid[count, 1] = msole.increment_id;
                grid[count, 2] = msole.shipping_name;
                grid[count, 3] = shipTo.company;
                grid[count, 4] = shipTo.street;
                grid[count, 5] = msole.postcode;
                grid[count, 6] = shipTo.city;
                grid[count, 7] = shipTo.region;
                grid[count, 8] = shipTo.country_id;
                grid[count, 9] = msole.weight;
                grid[count, 10] = msole.grand_total;
                grid[count, 11] = msole.shipping_description;


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error retieving orders: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private async void GetOrderInfo(string orderID)
    {
       await Program.MagentoService._mageService.salesOrderInfoAsync(Program.MagentoService._sessionKey, orderID);

    }
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629095/cannot-await-void-error-in-windows-phone. Possible duplicate?

Comment: Thank you for your respence but I am new to this topic and I have troubles drawing parallels to Magento usage. Is there a possibility that you could help me more?

Comment: Can you re-create your SOAP client proxy? Does it have a method `salesOrderInfoTaskAsync`?